# how to feed pictures and videos from my wall using facebook api

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook API

https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

It is not fetching all contents from news feed like pictures, videos shared on my wall by my friends, Posts in which i am tagged. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the correct GET variables to the Graph Api, like this:

```
734778xxx?fields=id,name,photos.fields(images,icon),email,posts.fields(comments.fields(message))
```

Go to this page and test it yourself
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

If you need individual tokens you can construct something like this,

```
<?php 
 require_once("facebook.php");//download & more info here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

 $config = array(
   'appId' => FBAPPID,
   'secret' => FBAPPSECRET,
);
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$fbuserid = $facebook->getUser();

$params = array(
"scope" => "read_stream,email,user_about_me", //here you ask for the parameters you need
"redirect_uri" => "http://www.yoursite.com/"
);

//getting the info
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
$fname = $user_profile["first_name"];
$lname = $user_profile["last_name"];
$email = $user_profile["email"];

?>
```

Comment: thanks, Ron, it works and i am very close but it requires individual token.I think Individual tokens get expire after some time so how can i generate it at runtime.